# sql queries what changes are necessary to obtain a result

Tags: php, mysql, database, http-post

I have a table in database with column names :

```
Name
Department
organization
location
year
email
```

I have a form that has 3 name attribute values: `department`, `year`, `organization`.

When a user fills any of these attributes, I want it to be posted to my PHP script which will then query results based on only the attributes that are filled.

eg:

- case 1:Form data filled is department and company and year is left null
- case 2: from data filled is company and year department is null, and such cases.

How can I modify my below query script so that I get the desired results?

```
// Conneced to server and select database.

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE dept =$_post['dept'] and year =$_post['year'] and company  =$_post['commpany'];
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use dynamic where like

```
$where = "WHERE 1 ";

if(isset($_POST['dept']) && $_POST['dept']!="")
{
      $dept = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dept']);
      $where .= " AND dept='$dept' ";
}

if(isset($_POST['year']) && $_POST['year']!="")
{
      $year = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
      $where .= " AND year='$year' ";
}

if(isset($_POST['commpany']) && $_POST['commpany']!="")
{
      $commpany = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['commpany']);
      $where .= " AND commpany='$commpany' ";
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM `$tbl_name` ".$where;
```

**NOTE:** `mysql_*` is deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: can you elaborate how the final query would look like if both company and year have values, and dept is null? and what does $where= "where1" do?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `$tbl_name` WHERE 1 AND dept='some_dept' AND year='some_year'